# Ignore certain hosts in last log

Tags: authentication, pam, last

I have an ansible job that uses `ssh` to perform tasks on many servers. It uses an authorized key to gain entry. When I run the `last` command it just shows a long list of root logins from the ansible host.

```
root@myserver:/# last
root     pts/1        ansiblehost.mydomain Tue Jan  2 7:00 - 7:00  (00:00)    
root     pts/1        ansiblehost.mydomain Tue Jan  2 8:00 - 8:00  (00:00)    
root     pts/1        ansiblehost.mydomain Tue Jan  2 9:00 - 9:00  (00:00)    
root     pts/1        ansiblehost.mydomain Tue Jan  2 10:00 - 10:00  (00:00)    
root     pts/1        ansiblehost.mydomain Tue Jan  2 11:00 - 11:00  (00:00)
```

I would like to suppress these entries from occurring because it fills up the screen and prevents me from investigating who has been logging in to the server.

Alternately, I would accept a way to set up my own logging of authentication for certain groups. For instance, if a user, who is in the admin group, logs in (`ssh` or terminal) it will make an entry in a log file `/var/log/logins.log`.